# Is there a way to disable logging in SQL server queue?

Tags: sql-server, logging

I have SQL event logged filled by these kind of messages and bloats the event log file. Is there a way to disable logging of receiving Queue messages?

The activated proc '[dbo].[QueueReceiveTriggerProcedure]' running on queue 'xxx.dbo.xxxQueue' output the following:  '3301'

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87343/3690

Answer (score 1):

Check the code of `dbo.QueueReceiveTriggerProcedure`, the output is being logged because the procedure has a `select` or `print` or `raiserror` statement.

[Cross-site duplicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87343/3690) courtesy Martin Smith.